# Trying to fix an overflow issue that causes text to overflow on a new line to the left

Tags: html, css

I don't post here often at all but only when I am stumped and I fos sure am.

I have a div tag with inside an article tag and the div tag wont extend the background held by the article tag.

The code I have is split into many different files to use jsfiddle so I'll post it here and provide screen shots of what is happening. If you guys can figure it out an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

This is a screen shot of whats happening, I want the twitter to be above the twitter widget, but it overflows under the facebook rather then extending the article background down.

This is the CSS: https://pastebin.com/y1MPG6rV
It is to many characters to paste here.

Image of whats happening on my end: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B04n1.jpg

This is the HTML:

```
        <!-- Wrapper -->
        <div id="wrapper">
                <!-- About -->
                <article id="about">
                    <h2 class="major">About.</h2>
                    <span class="image main"><img src="images/fbcover.jpg" alt="" /></span>
                    <div class="medias"><center>
                    <div>
                    <span>Facebook</span>
                    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FDelusionsEntertainment%2F&tabs&width=340&height=180&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="300" height="180"
                        style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cust">
                    <span>Twitter</span>
                    <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="305" data-height="356" data-theme="light" href="https://twitter.com/DelusionsENT?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by DelusionsENT</a>
                    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
                    </div>
                    </center></div>
                </article>
</div>

            <!-- Footer -->
            <footer id="footer">
                <p class="copyright">Delusions Entertainment™</p>
            </footer>

        </div>

        <!-- BG -->
        <div id="bg"></div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            /* Demo purposes only */
        $(".hover").mouseleave(
          function() {
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
          }
        );
        </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fixed height you can use this:

```
.medias { height:auto }
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I missed that. Thanks for your help!